# Last item on ScrollViewer is truncated after changing Windows State

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem where after changing the window state from Maximize to normal, the last item seen on the ScrollViewer is truncated.

The problem is solved if I adjust the Window size. But why is this happening and how do I solve the issue without adjusting Window size?

```
<Window x:Class="Doodle.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Doodle"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow4" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TabControl.Style" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="HorizontalOnly"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="LineLeftButton" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="left"
                                      Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}"
                                      Visibility="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer, Path=ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="LineRightButton" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="right"
                                      Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}"
                                      Visibility="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer, Path=ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Focusable="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                              CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll}"
                                              PanningMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.PanningMode}"
                                              Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled="{TemplateBinding Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled}">
                                        <ScrollViewer.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                                            <ScrollContentPresenter/>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ScrollViewer.Style>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="itemsPresenter" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Style="{StaticResource TabControl.Style}">
            <TabItem Header="1aaldsjalkjdalkjdal"/>
            <TabItem Header="1aaldsjalkjdalkjdal"/>
            <TabItem Header="1aaldsjalkjdalkjdal"/>
            <TabItem Header="1aaldsjalkjdalkjdal"/>
            <TabItem Header="1aaldsjalkjdalkjdal"/>
            <TabItem Header="1aaldsjalkjdalkjdal"/>
            <TabItem Header="1aaldsjalkjdalkjdal"/>
            <TabItem Header="1aaldsjalkjdalkjdal"/>
            <TabItem Header="1aaldsjalkjdalkjdal"/>
            <TabItem Header="1aaldsjalkjdalkjdal"/>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

To reproduce the problem:

1. simply launch the app
2. maximize window
3. set it back to normal size
4. try to click the right button to scroll until the most right

you will notice that the text "1aaldsjalkjdalkjdal" is truncated until in the middle.

[image: this is truncated]

[image: this is ok, which I want to solve after setting back window to normal]

I was thinking to force the TabControl to redraw by using

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.StateChanged += (o, e) =>
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, (Action)(() =>
    {
        this.InvalidateVisual();
        this.UpdateLayout();
    }));
};
```

as a solution, but ... nope! It didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @mjwills I just added the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to put the `DockPanel` with the `RepeatButtons` inside the `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Focusable="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                              CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll}"
                                              PanningMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.PanningMode}"
                                              Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled="{TemplateBinding Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled}">
                <ScrollViewer.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                    <DockPanel>
                                        <RepeatButton x:Name="LineLeftButton" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="left"
                                                                          Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}"
                                                                          Visibility="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer, Path=ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                        <RepeatButton x:Name="LineRightButton" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="right"
                                                                          Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}"
                                                                          Visibility="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer, Path=ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ScrollViewer.Style>
                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="itemsPresenter" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```